# Tesseract not able to distinguish between zero and O

Tags: python, tesseract

I have a large image from which I need to extract some information. I am using Python opencv library for image enhancement. Using opencv methods I extracted a part of the image that interests me. It is given below.

[image]

Tesseract is not able to distinguish between 0 and O. It is giving output as all zeroes. I tried with `--psm` options 6 and others, but to no avail. I am using the latest stable release of tesseract (v3) on windows.

I am continuing to work on this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

I found a solution for this. Used box output from tesseract. Need to give `makebox` as an argument to tesseract command. The box output contains the `X` and `Y` coordinates of a 'box' around each character read. I derived the ratio of width to height and with some input images trained a Logistic Regression Model to predict the output a 0 or O. Then I used this trained model for test images and it worked like a charm.

Comment: You should try with latest beta version ([Tesseract 4.0 Beta](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/4.0-with-LSTM)) which use LSTM to recognize characters. It should give far better results.

Comment: I need to use whitelist characters and support for that in Tesseract 4.0 Beta is missing/broken currently.

Comment: Well, you could try using OpenCv to do a bit of filtering. You know that all zeros have minor width than O letters. You can extract all digits and then, using Tesseract to identify numbers and letters (based on width dimension).

Comment: The idea of using 'width' sounds promising. I will explore more and will update the forum with my findings.

Comment: @Pulkit Kansal how did you find the box for every character? I am applying some logics to break the word into characters. Is there any inbuilt feature in tesseract to get each character box?

Comment: Could you answer your question instead of editing the question? also to provide the sample that's working for you. Thanks!